# How to unit test a click event of a button which is inside a private function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a private function in a service that looks like this. How do I write a unit test for the click event of that button? The button is inside a dialog.

1) Is that even unit testable?
2) Since I've mentioned that this is inside a service and click event is involved, should it be tested like a component? meaning I have to setup TestBed so I can actually click the button, if yes, how? OR is there a more correct way to write a unit test for it, if so, how?

Thank you!

```
public callOpenDialog(){
   openDialog(formA, dataView, {}, true);
}
private openDialog(formA: FormA, dataView: DataView, placeholder: ViewContainerRef, okToAll: boolean): Observable<ResponseRequiredResult> {
    return new Observable<ResponseRequiredResult>(observer => {
      let dlgComponent: ResponseRequiredModalFormComponent;
      let dialog: DialogRef<ResponseRequiredModalFormComponent>;
      const dialogId = 'ResponseRequired';

      let buttons = [
        {
          id: this.lmUniqueIdService.uniqueId([formA.busFormA.name, dialogId, DialogButtonKey.OK]),
          text: Locale.translate(DialogButtonKey.OK),
          validate : false,
          isDefault: true,
          click: (e, modal) => {
            if (this.validateResponseRequiredForm(formA.busFormA, dlgComponent.formComponent.formModel)) {
              dialog.close(<ResponseRequiredResult> {
                result:     ResponseRequiredDialogResult.RESPONSE_OK,
                specFields: formA.busFormA.fields, model: dlgComponent.formComponent.formModel
              });
            }
          }
        }
      ];

     dialog = modalDialogService
      .modal(ResponseRequiredModalFormComponent, placeholder)
      .buttons(buttons)
      .title(Locale.translate('ResponseRequired'))
      .isAlert(true)
      .open();
}
```

Comment: You could extract the `click` callback in its own function and test that function. You don't need to test the triggering of the click, this should be tested in the `ModalDialogService` or the `ResponseRequiredModalFormComponent `.

Comment: @AntoineB how can I extract it?

Comment: Just put it as a normal function on your component and pass it instead of using an anonymous function when you open the dialog.

Comment: @AntoineB is there any other way aside from changing the component? I don't want to adjust the component just so I can write a unit test for that specific part of code.

Comment: What are you trying to test? There does not appear to be any valid reason why this needs to be an anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

This code is poorly-structured and needs to be re-written for testability. As it is currently structured, this code is not testable at all. Problems:

1. Click executes inside not one, but two anonymous methods.
2. The observable doesn't return any value (after the dialog opens), so there is no way to get the buttons array from it.

If you need to be able to test the code, you need to declare them as methods on your component or update the code to return your buttons array (or better yet, a complete class that has all of the context you need).

Answer (score 4):

You can call private functions from unit-tests and you should not depend on click event.

```
service = TestBed.get(PushNotificationService);
service['openDialog'](a, b, c, d);
```

Just call the private function using the square bracket and pass argument normally. I have used it at many places in my code base